# Запуск функции при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, функции

Необходимо запустить функцию JS автоматически при открытии страницы. Сейчас она запускается по нажатию, нужно сделать автоматически.

```
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Вызвать функцию</button>     
       <script>
     function myFunction() {
        // КОД
         }
       </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно создать слушатель

На чистом js :

```
<script>
  function ready() {
    alert( 'DOM готов' );
  }

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
Fun1();
Func2();
```

});

На jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("hellow world!!!!");
});
```

Этот код запустится после загрузки страницы

Comment: addEventListener - не нашел в интернете толкового объяснения что это такое. Это авто-воспроизведение функци?

Comment: Это слушатель, он реагирует на определенное событие, в данном случае событие DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Когда событие происходит, вызывается функция, переданная вторым параметром

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня нет в коде DOM. Может быть можно сделать автоматическое нажатие на кнопку, а она уже вызовет функцию?

Comment: Может вы не совсем понимаете что такое DOM? Вы просто попробуйте использовать эту функцию

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model

Comment: для jQuery рекомендуется синтаксис `jQuery(function($){`

Comment: Данным способом можно вызвать несколько функций? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", functionOne); document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", functionTwo);

Comment: Да, сколько угодно

Comment: А через запятую? Вот так: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", functionOne, functionTwo);

Comment: Нет, так нельзя, но ты можешь вызвать одну функцию, в которой будут вызываться другие функции

Comment: Дополнил пример в ответе

Comment: @Holter, у вас ещё остались вопросы?

Comment: Поставьте галочку, не оставляйте вопрос открытым :)